# Transfer function of a system regulating current

Tags: mosfet, control-system, small-signal

Here is the circuit with two different MOSFETs :

[image]

The circuit controls the current through the resistors R3 or R1 via a reference voltage (V1 and V3).

As you can see there is an inductor. I plot the transfer function of the closed loop system which is dependent on the value of the inductor and the resistor as it acts as a pole (R/L):

[image: ![enter image description here]

(The gain is lower than 1 as there is a resistor (1/R))

As you can see the two closed loop response are exactly the same. But this not what I was expecting. It seems that the MOSFET has no effect on the transfer function. But it should have an effect. As there is obviously the MOSFET capacitor to charge, so it should add a pole. Also, the rdson between MOSFET are not exactly the same, so this rdson should add with the 3 Ω resistors and move the pole frequency linked to the inductors?

So How to do to see the effect of the MOSFET?

Thank you :)

Comment: What's "ron"? Rdson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Transfer function of a system regulating current*

It's **not** regulating current; it uses closed loop control to regulate the voltage at the junction of R1 and the MOSFET source. Given the presence of the inductor, it **cannot** regulate current in R1 (or R3) at high frequencies. It's a voltage regulator.

> *It seems that the MOSFET has no effect on the transfer function. But
> it should have an effect. As there is obviously the MOSFET capacitor
> to charge, so it should add a pole.*

Closing the loop "bypasses" the "expected" MOSFET parasitic capacitance problems.

You can prove this by getting rid of the MOSFET and driving the source node directly via a resistor and a capacitor to ground: -

[image]

The effect of the RC will be largely eradicated due to closing the loop and having such a strong open-loop gain of 100,000. Here's my version that uses a 10 nF capacitor to ground: -

[image]

I'm looking at the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2

> *The circuit controls the current through the resistors R3 or R1 via a
> reference voltage (V1 and V3)*

Actually, your circuit and my circuit control the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2 (mine) and the junction of R1 (or R3) and the MOSFET source (your circuit). Because of this, there is no point looking at the current through R1 (or R3) because it will naturally erode due to the presence of the 10 μH inductor.

Let me repeat again; our circuits **do not** regulate current and hence, looking at the current makes no sense if we are trying to understand how negative feedback coupled with high open-loop gain can overcome MOSFET parasitic capacitance.

Here's a slightly altered circuit with R1 = 3 Ω: -

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. You suggest to open loop to see the effect of the MOSFET ? You mean I have to replace the MOSFET by a capacitor ? in order to see the mosfet pole ? Also I do not get why a strong open loop gain of 100000 will eradicate the problem. If there is a strong gain and a phase shift due to the inductor and the capacitor at low frequencies, it will be non stable. And if it is not possible to play on the locations of the pole, it will be better to reduce rapidly the gain ?

Comment: I did **not** suggest opening the loop. Look at the image in my answer. I replaced the MOSFET with a capacitor. You should run that circuit I propose and see that for a large range of capacitance (zero to several nanofarads), the closed-loop bode plot is hardly affected. It's hardly affected because of the closed-loop control and massive open-loop gain. Start lowering the open-loop gain from 100,000 to 10,000 then to 1,000 and see the effect of the capacitor starting to be seen. @Jess

Comment: So, I'm just trying to get you to set-up a simple circuit where the MOSFET is replaced by a capacitor so you can believe for yourself that the effect of the capacitor is vastly diminished by the closed-loop control. Then, as you reduce the gain of the controller, the effect of the capacitor is more easily seen.

Comment: I am not sur that your system understudies is the same, isn't it ? It will at least move the operating point.

Comment: @Jess I'm trying to demonstrate to you that the closed-loop control overcomes the MOSFET drain-source capacitance. I see one trivial difference in that you have R1 as 3 ohm and I have it as 1 ohm. It is a trivial difference too but I can replace my picture if you want if it convinces you.

Comment: We are not looking the same transfer function. I am looking the current through the resistors. I do not understand the results of your transfer function. The gain at low frequencies should be equal to 1, isn'it ?

Comment: I think your system is not converging because the feedback cannot be equal to 1V when the capacitor is equal to 1V, i.e when no current flow through the resistor and the inductance

Comment: @Jess firstly, our circuits **ARE NOT** current regulators. Both our circuits regulate the voltage on one node of R1. In other words, both circuits are voltage regulators so, trying to look at the current through the resistor is bound to show the roll-off at 50 kHz. This is due to the natural blocking action of the inductor. Hence, to demonstrate that closed-loop control eradicates the effect of MOSFET parasitics, it is necessary to look at the node that is regulated (and not the current through R1). If you are trying to design a current regulator, you need a different circuit.

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that it changes the bandwidth according to what is the gain of the "op amp". I will repost a question. Thank you for your help :)